# Gaussian blur not working correctly

Tags: opengl, shaders, blur

So pretty much I tried to add a gaussian blur to something I am making and it is acting oddly. The setup is like:

```
[All framebuffers are cleared to rgba(0,0,0,0), normal blend enabled]
Draw some solid black objects to Framebuffer 0
Apply horizontal gaussian pass from Framebuffer 0 to Framebuffer 1 (this works fine)
Apply vertical gaussian pass from Framebuffer 1 to backbuffer
[original black objects removed here, does not affect the process at all]
```

It seems like a standard gaussian layout, but the problem happens with the final view (presumably the vertical pass). It appears that the vertical gaussian pass dampened the previous horizontal one, making it a lot thinner (and making the box shadow effect I was going for look weird):

[image: Example of the problem]
(note on the right image on one of the center rectangles for example, the top and bottom are blurred like they should but the sides aren't)

I just cant figure out why the vertical blur factor is at least 2x the horizontal one. I feel like this is because of something to due with alpha because the horizontal pass displays like it should until the second step happens. One final note, this still happens if I flip the horiz/vert order, it just happens on the other axis. I honestly can't figure this out so any help would be nice. Also for more info, heres the fragment shader I use (all the data passed to it is correct):

```
in vec2 ftexpos;

uniform sampler2D inputtex;
uniform vec2 vector;


float[15] gaussianraito = float[15](
    0.023089,
    0.034587,
    0.048689,
    0.064408,
    0.080066,
    0.093531,
    0.102673,
    0.105915,
    0.102673,
    0.093531,
    0.080066,
    0.064408,
    0.048689,
    0.034587,
    0.023089
);

void main() {
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);

    for (int i = -7; i < 7; i++) {
        sum += texture(inputtex, vec2(ftexpos.x + i * vector.x, ftexpos.y + i * vector.y)) * gaussianraito[i + 7];
    }

    gl_FragColor = sum;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be applying both an X and a Y offset (I think, I do HLSL usually), which means you'll be sampling a diagonal line of pixels. The two stage gaussian blur should only offset in X in the horizontal pass, and only offset in Y on the vertical pass.

Comment: @Martin Yea it does, the uniform is just changed from (1 screen pixel width, 0) to (0, 1 screen pixel height) with the different passes

Comment: I tried another thing (setting the framebuffer colors to a non-alpha one) and the blurring works fine. Why does alpha make it do that (is the formula wrong or something)?

Comment: try `gl_FragColor = vec4(sum.rgb, 1);`